# Serving region-specific S3 buckets via CloudFront

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I have two private S3 buckets, in different regions, served via CloudFront with a custom domain name.

What I would like to do is have different S3 buckets in each region to be served and have CloudFront serve those buckets (via Edge) via my custom domain name.

However, I think my understanding of Origins and Origin Groups is lacking...

Given I can only have two origins in a group, how can CloudFront be configured to reference more than 2 buckets as origins?

Comment: What's your motivation for this setup? Do you need to serve different assets by region?

Comment: Yes. I would like to employ S3 and CloudFront to serve a slightly different version of an SPA based on region.

Comment: A simpler way to do this is to use CloudFront Functions (CF2) with a single bucket. For example, if you were to store files in S3 with a country prefix, you could use CF2 to rewrite the URL to the correct country prefix based on the user's location. Take a look at these examples: [redirect by country](https://github.com/aws-samples/amazon-cloudfront-functions/tree/main/redirect-based-on-country) and [rewrite](https://github.com/aws-samples/amazon-cloudfront-functions/tree/main/url-rewrite-single-page-apps)

Comment: Can I not simply create a bucket in each region of interest and link it to a distribution as an origin?